# Javascript Array of Objects - Determine if key-value exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I feel like an idiot, but I just can't figure this one out. I'm creating an array of objects:

```
var files = [];

for (var a = 0; a < data.Attachments.length; a++) {
    files.push({
        id: data.Attachments[a].ID,
        name: data.Attachments[a].Name, 
        size: data.Attachments[a].Size, 
        extension: data.Attachments[a].Extension 
    });                 
}
```

And I need to prevent duplicate entries from being added to the array. I've tried a variety of ways to access and check the existing IDs before pushing the new row (including [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-array-of-javascript-objects)), but nothing has worked. I'm sure it's some little thing I'm just missing.

Here's what a console.log of the files array looks like after it's been populated (it's looping through multiple items and creating an array for each of them; some items don't have attachments):
[image]

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: @hindmost - Sorry, accidentally posted before finishing. Check it now.

Comment: Show what have you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can setup a cache object to record what has already been added to the array. Each time before you wanna push a new item into the array, check if that item is already recorded in the cache object. If it is, continue to the next item; otherwise push it into the array.

Something like this:

```
var files = [];
var cache = {};

for (var a = 0; a < data.Attachments.length; a++) {
    if (!cache.hasOwnerProperty(data.Attachments[a].ID)) {
        files.push({
            id: data.Attachments[a].ID,
            name: data.Attachments[a].Name, 
            size: data.Attachments[a].Size, 
            extension: data.Attachments[a].Extension 
        });
        cache[data.Attachments[a].ID] = 0 // doesn't matter what value you assign
    }                 
}
```

Hope this helps and let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly! (I did have to change it to "hasOwnProperty").

Comment: Oops ... Sorry, typo :)